# Setting up multiple spinners in android

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have 2 spinners in my project and so far only have one spinner working! i am trying to have 2 spinners that when selected change the image in the imageview! the first spinner takes data from an array in the strings.xml and would also like the second array to do the same and update the imageview like the first one does! after trial and error i cant figure out how to do this and edited code back to the one spinner!

```
public class SpinnerRes extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final String[] spstr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinnervalue);
        final Spinner sp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> ar = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spstr);
        sp.setAdapter(ar);

        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int arg2, long arg3) {
                final ImageView im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                String s=((TextView)arg1).getText().toString();
                if(s.equals("A"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a));
                if(s.equals("A6"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a6));
                if(s.equals("A7"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a7));
                if(s.equals("Am"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.am));

                if(s.equals("Am6"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.am6));
                if(s.equals("Am7"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.am7));
                if(s.equals("Amaj7"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.amaj7));
                if(s.equals("img8"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img4));

                if(s.equals("img9"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img1));
                if(s.equals("img10"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img2));
                if(s.equals("img11"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img3));
                if(s.equals("img12"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img4));

                if(s.equals("img13"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img1));
                if(s.equals("img14"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img2));
                if(s.equals("img15"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img3));
                if(s.equals("img16"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img4));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

    }
}
```

The xml with the 2 spinners..

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="31dp">
</Spinner>
<Spinner
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="18dp">
</Spinner>
```

The strings.xml file with the 2 arrays

```
<string-array name="spinnervalue">
    <item>A</item>
    <item>A6</item>
    <item>A7</item>
    <item>Am</item>
    <item>Am6</item>
    <item>Am7</item>
    <item>Amaj7</item>
    <item>img8</item>
    <item>img9</item>
    <item>img10</item>
    <item>img11</item>
    <item>img12</item>
    <item>img13</item>
    <item>img14</item>
    <item>img15</item>
    <item>img16</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="spinnervalue2">
    <item>A</item>
    <item>A6</item>
    <item>A7</item>
    <item>Am</item>
    <item>Am6</item>
    <item>Am7</item>
    <item>Amaj7</item>
    <item>img8</item>
    <item>img9</item>
    <item>img10</item>
    <item>img11</item>
    <item>img12</item>
    <item>img13</item>
    <item>img14</item>
    <item>img15</item>
    <item>img16</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: where is your second spinner initialisation and adapter setting?

Comment: i removed it as was getting errors so edited code back to one spinner!

Comment: what kind of errors?

Comment: where is your imageview in xml?

Comment: i initailised the second spinner, then tried to set up another adapter but would not work! i could type all the code up again to replicate the errors if you wish? im just looking for a simple effecient way to have what i am looking for! someone mentioned to me to create 2 adapters and use a switch stament in the onItemSelect but dont think that would work

Comment: would you like me to add the imageview? didnt think would be needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this approach:

```
public class SpinnerRes extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                final String[] spstr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinnervalue);
                final Spinner sp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

                final ArrayAdapter<String> ar = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spstr);
                sp.setAdapter(ar);

               sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

            }

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

             Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
             if(spinner.getId() == R.id.spinner1)
             {
               //do your staff                   
             }
             else if(spinner.getId() == R.id.spinner2)
             {
               //do your staff
             }

          }

    }
```

Comment: This saved me. Thanks for the simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please look in to this code do changes according to you,

```
    public class SpinnerRes extends Activity {
     ImageView im;
    Spinner sp,sp2;
     String[] spstr;
    String[] spstr2;
    ArrayAdapter<String> ar;
    ArrayAdapter<String> ar2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.b);
        im = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        spstr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinnervalue);
        spstr2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinnervalue2);
        sp = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        sp2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        ar = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spstr);
        ar2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,spstr2);
        sp.setAdapter(ar);
        sp2.setAdapter(ar2);

        sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int arg2, long arg3) {

                String text = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if(text.equals("A"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
                if(text.equals("A6"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.built_in_active));


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                       int arg2, long arg3) {

                String text = sp2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                if(text.equals("A"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
                if(text.equals("A6"))
                    im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.built_in_active));


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: will try with this code also and let you know, appreciate your help